# Django 2.0 está estável para uso em produção?

Tags: django-2.0

Gostaria de saber se posso migrar para o Django 2.0 e usar essa versão em produção, sem me preocupar com bugs absurdos. Vou ter que atualizar algumas libs e encontrar soluções para as desatualizadas (até ai tranquilo).

Comment: Eles se classificam como estável: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ (redirecionado de https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/). Quem sou eu para julgar isso, né? Tentei ver quantas e quais `issues` abertas tinha, mas acho que a visão mobile do GitHub não ajudou: https://github.com/django/django

Comment: Obrigado, dei uma olhada aqui nas issues. Quem não arrisca não petisca, bora migrar!

Comment: Estou esperando sua resposta para saber mais do Django 2.0 então

Comment: Conseguiu migrar? Tem algum comentário/ressalva a fazer para quem for ler esse conteúdo em um futuro próximo?

Comment: Conseguimos (equipe aqui), bem tranquilo! Vou publicar uma resposta com o resultado. Estamos usando em produção já também.

Answer (score 1):

Fizemos a migração aqui do Django 1.8 para o 2.0. Foi bem tranquilo a migração em si. **Tivemos que atualizar algumas libs no `requeriments.txt` que estavam gerando error nos logs**, mas nada de absurdo. Fizemos isso manualmente, até que não foram tantas libs.

Notamos que mudou um pouco a estrutura de **URLS**. Precisamos definir agora dentro das `urls.py` de cada app, um `app_name` (o namespace dentro da `urls.py` do projeto raiz). Veja no exemplo:

```
myapp/
- urls.py
urlpatterns = [   
    url(r'^noticias/', include('apps.news.urls', namespace='news')),
]
```

Usamos namespaces para trabalhar melhor a forma de organizar as urls dentro do app. Na versão nova do Django, precisamos especificar esse namespace dentro das urls internas de cada app

```
**myapp/
- apps/
- - news/
- - - urls.py**

app_name="news"  
urlpatterns = [      
    url(r'^$', view.list, name='home'),
...
]
```

Outra coisa que percebemos, é como a versão está tratando os acessos as rotas. Antes recebíamos **Warnings** pois não tinhamos a rota `/favicon.ico`. Essa rota era sempre chamada, algo relacionado com padrão de navegadores. Agora está alertando como **Error**. Fora isso estamos recebendo como error também diversas rotas de invasão (devem ser bots tentando invadir com rotas aleatórias como `/wp-admin`, etc).

Um link que chamou nossa atenção para querer migrar para versão 2.0, [é uma publicação informando sobre as atualizações de segurança do Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/weblog/2018/feb/01/security-releases/). Aqui gostamos de sempre estar atualizados com as novas versões, para não ficar preso no tempo. Vamos ter que acompanhar mais essas noticias. Por isso joguei a pergunta aqui, para saber se alguém já estava utilizando.

**Conclusão**

Até o momento não encontramos problemas graves. Estamos em produção já e está tudo funcionando normalmente. Vai sem medo :)